# References from Python Bigquery Client don't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery, service-accounts

Im having troubles running the following code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(BQJSONKEY,project = BQPROJECT)
dataset = client.dataset(BQDATASET)
assert not dataset.exists()
```

The following error pop up:
`'DatasetReference' object has no attribute 'exists'`

Similarly when i do:

`table = dataset.table(BQTABLE)`

i get: `'TableReference' object has no attribute 'exists'`

However, according to the docs it should work:
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery/usage.html#datasets

here is my `pip freeze` (the part with google-cloud):

```
gapic-google-cloud-datastore-v1==0.15.3
gapic-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1==0.15.3
gapic-google-cloud-logging-v2==0.91.3
gevent==1.2.2
glob2==0.5
gmpy2==2.0.8
google-api-core==0.1.1
google-auth==1.2.1
google-cloud==0.30.0
google-cloud-bigquery==0.28.0
google-cloud-bigtable==0.28.1
google-cloud-core==0.28.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.4.0
google-cloud-dns==0.28.0
google-cloud-error-reporting==0.28.0
google-cloud-firestore==0.28.0
google-cloud-language==1.0.0
google-cloud-logging==1.4.0
google-cloud-monitoring==0.28.0
google-cloud-pubsub==0.29.1
google-cloud-resource-manager==0.28.0
google-cloud-runtimeconfig==0.28.0
google-cloud-spanner==0.29.0
google-cloud-speech==0.30.0
google-cloud-storage==1.6.0
google-cloud-trace==0.16.0
google-cloud-translate==1.3.0
google-cloud-videointelligence==0.28.0
google-cloud-vision==0.28.0
google-gax==0.15.16
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3
```

I wonder how can i fix it and make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you got to this docs but you should be using these as reference:

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html#datasets

Code for `0.28` would be something like:

```
dataset_refence = client.dataset(BQDATASET)
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_reference)
assert dataset.created is not None
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to create the dataset before calling `exists()`

```
dataset = client.dataset(BQDATASET)
dataset.create() 
assert not dataset.exists()
```

Comment: but i do dataset = client.dataset(BQDATASET) where BQDATASET is a dataset name. So i expect to get True from my code. Not sure `create` is relevant here?

Comment: hmmmm. ok let me try somethinf else